# how to get file path set in appender in logback.xml

Tags: java, filepath, logback, appender

I want file path (along with file name) set in appender in logback.xml
which class i need to use. please help. following is my appender

```
<appender name="SIFT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
    <discriminator class="com.hotwaxmedia.logger.ThreadNameBasedDiscriminator"/>
    <sift>
        <appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
            <file>runtime/logs/app-${threadName}.html</file>
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                <pattern>%p %d ${threadName} [%logger{0} : %-5level] %msg%n%rEx</pattern>
            </layout>
        </appender>
    </sift>
</appender>
```

Comment: and what problems are you having?

Comment: i just want to get file path (i.e runtime/logs/app-${threadName}.html)
in my java code. so is there any class or method that return file path.

Answer (score 2):

You could load the appender programatically

```
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
for (Logger logger : context.getLoggerList()) {
  for (Iterator<Appender<ILoggingEvent>> index = logger.iteratorForAppenders();     index.hasNext();) {
     Appender<ILoggingEvent> appender = index.next();
  }
}
```

then you could verify is the `appender` is a `FileAppender` and the call the `getFile()`. Take a look at the doc http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/FileAppender.html

Answer (score 0):

This issue related to [LOGBACK-833](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-833) which was fixed in logback version 1.0.12. Thus, you need to upgrade to logback version 1.0.12 or later. The discriminator instance has to define "threadName" as the key to export. Otherwise, ${threadName} cannot be resolved. Here is the modified discriminator:

```
<discriminator class="com.hotwaxmedia.logger.ThreadNameBasedDiscriminator">
  <!-- the key to export needs to be defined -->
  <key>threadName</key>
</discriminator>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must user path in "fileNamePattern" tag , for example:

```
    <Discriminator>

        <Key>userId</Key>

        <DefaultValue>general</DefaultValue>

    </Discriminator>



    <sift>

        <appender name="FILE-MODULENAME-${userId}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

                <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                  <!-- rollover daily -->
                  <fileNamePattern>/opt/webligic12/user_projects/domains/myDomain/servers/AdminServer/logs/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}/byUser/modulename/${userId}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
                  <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                    <!-- or whenever the file size reaches maxFileSize -->
                    <maxFileSize>2MG</maxFileSize>
                  </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
                </rollingPolicy>


            <Append>true</Append>

            <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">

                <Pattern>%d %X{user} %level %msg %n</Pattern>

            </encoder>

        </appender>

    </sift>

</appender>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to fGo's answer, you can get log file path like this (assume your appender name is "SIFT"):

```
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
for (Logger logger : context.getLoggerList()) {
  for (Iterator<Appender<ILoggingEvent>> index = logger.iteratorForAppenders();     index.hasNext();) {
     Appender<ILoggingEvent> appender = index.next();
     if (appender.getName().equals("SIFT")) {
        FileAppender<ILoggingEvent> fileAppender = (FileAppender) appender;
        System.out.println(fileAppender.getFile());
     }
  }
}
```